# Unable to select div (generated dynamically) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a popup box that retrieves content data via AJAX and displays this content. This is taken care of by the asynchronous function `generateInfoboxContent()` and the HTML content retrieved is `boxText`. The content that will be displayed depends on the item that was clicked by the user. `infoboxes[i].setContent` and `infoboxes[i].open()` are functions that add the content to the HTML page.

**Problem:** I want to select a div `infobox_header_favorite` within this dynamically generated content `boxText` using jQuery using `.click()` but the click handler does not seem to be triggered! How can I solve his problem?

**jQuery Code**

```
(function(i) {
    var boxText = generateInfoboxContent(infoboxes[i].listing_id, function(boxText) {
        infoboxes[i].setContent(boxText);
        infoboxes[i].open(map, markers[i]);
        infoboxes[i].show();
        infoboxes_open.push(infoboxes[i]);

        console.log('Hello');
        // Favorite function
        $("#infobox_header_favorite").click(function() {
            console.log('favorite!');
            toggleFavorite(infoboxes[i].listing_id);
        });
    });
})(i);
```

**Result**

`Hello` is written to the console, but `favorite!` is not written to the console log when the div `infobox_header_favorite` is clicked.

**UPDATE**

**jQuery Code**

```
$.getJSON(base_url + 'index.php/main/getplaces', 
    { data: data }, 
    function(json){


        for( i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

            (function(i) {
                var boxText = generateInfoboxContent(infoboxes[i].listing_id, function(boxText) {
                    infoboxes[i].setContent(boxText);
                    infoboxes[i].open(map, markers[i]);
                    infoboxes[i].show();
                    infoboxes_open.push(infoboxes[i]);

                    console.log('Hello');
                    // Favorite function
                    $("#infobox_header_favorite").click(function() {
                        console.log('favorite!');
                        toggleFavorite(infoboxes[i].listing_id);
                    });
                });
            })(i);

        }


    });
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
for( i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

            (function(i) {
                var boxText = generateInfoboxContent(infoboxes[i].listing_id, function(boxText) {
                    infoboxes[i].setContent(boxText);
                    infoboxes[i].open(map, markers[i]);
                    infoboxes[i].show();
                    infoboxes_open.push(infoboxes[i]);

                    console.log('Hello');
                    // Favorite function
                    $("#infobox_header_favorite").on("click", function() {
                        console.log('asd');
                        toggleFavorite(infoboxes[i].listing_id);
                    });
                });
            })(i);

        }
```

Received an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'`

Comment: Is there an actual element with an id "#infobox_header_favorite" in your page? We need more info.

Comment: `<div id="infobox_header_favorite"></div>` is part of `boxText`. It does not exist until `infoboxes[i].open()` has executed.

Comment: what if you don't create more than one binding with infobox_header_favorite id? That or you are creating more than one element with the same id...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.live()` or `.on()` to bind event to dynamically added elements.

`.live()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7

Comment: Just updated the code to show a loop from `0 to json.length`, and in each loop I will be adding `$("#infobox_header_favorite").click(function())` because I need to pass a unique integer `infoboxes[i].listing_id` to the `toggleFavorite()` function inside the click handler. Can this be done using `.on()`? Will there be a confusion because there will be many `.on()` handlers and each will be passed a different integer?

Comment: Tried `$("#infobox_header_favorite").on('click')` but got an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'`

Comment: @Nyxynyx: pls check .on() syntax. You cab Refer link given by jrummell.